# string null check/ trim

Tags: java, strings, comparative-review

Minor question on String null check and trim.

```
// given a function func() that might return either a string or null
String func() {
    return "  hello  ";
}
```

Which one of the following is better - i.e. more readable, preferable, etc.?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String value = func(); // may return null
if (value != null && !value.trim().isEmpty()) {
    list.add(value.trim());
}
```

OR

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String value = func(); // may return null
if (value != null) {
    value = value.trim();
    if(!value.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more concrete detail to your question — see [ask]. What is the `list` for? Is this code running in a loop? What is `func()`? Why does it sometimes return `null`?

Comment: Corrected the question. Why -1 now?

Comment: You still haven't answered the questions in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I encounter similar cases, I use the Apache Commons Lang library. It has a `StringUtils` class with all sorts of useful String utilities. For null-safe check if a String is not all whitespaces, you can use the following:

```
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(value))
```

Here is the reference: [StringUtils.isBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-)

**EDIT #1**
just figured how to use `Optional` to eliminate one if question:

```
String value = Optional.ofNullable(func()).ifPresent(v -> v.trim()).orElse("");
if (!value.isEmpty()) {
    list.add(value);
}
```

**EDIT #2**
good pointer to the `map` function.  I was able to find the ultimate chain of functions that eliminates all if conditions!

```
    Optional.ofNullable(func())
            .map(v -> v.trim())
            .filter(v -> !v.isEmpty())
            .ifPresent(v -> list.add(v));
```

Comment: I should have added "without using StringUtils". I anyways have to call value.trim() before adding it to list.

Comment: thought of another idea. see edited answer

Comment: I guess, you do not need the second trim() ?

Comment: yes of course..

Comment: Actually, ifPresent() does not work, it should be "map"


`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String value = Optional.ofNullable(func()).map(v -> v.trim()).orElse("");
        if (!value.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(value);
        }
`

Comment: good pointer to the `map`.  I was able to find the ultimate chain of functions that eliminates all if conditions!